# How to add json4s library to Scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, json4s

Added to build.sbt file this line:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.2.11"
```

And i can't see that the library is added.
Maybe i need to do some build to this file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you do an SBT refresh?

You do that by clicking on the right sidebar, where it says "Sbt" and then in the top-left corner of the opened tab, there's a refresh button.

Comment: Yes it is helped. Thanks

Comment: But now when i just try to do

      **var json = parse ("something")**

The "parse" is in red (Cannot resolve symbol)

Comment: Hi @OrlovAndrey, were you able to build the 
def getRequest(jRequest: Json) function from http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/447042/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BD%D0%B0-scala